# Utilizing all Cores in SQL Sever Machine when calling SPs from C# program

Tags: sql, sql-server, multicore

I have a simple single threaded utility written in C# that inserts data into SQLServer DB using SP calls. The SQL Server machine has 8 core processor.

The problem is that the utility is running very slow and 4 of the cores show max utilization in task manager and other 4 are not utilized at all.

We also tried running multiple instances of the utility from different machines but still only the first 4 cores(shown in task manager) are utilized.

I don't have access to the SPs but it is fairly complicated and uses temp tables and inserts data into multiple tables.

Could anyone provide suggestions on how to find out what is causing only 4 cores to be utilized?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version and edition of SQL Server?  For 2005, only the Enterprise/Developer editions could use more than 4 cores - Standard is limited to four.

Reference:

- [SQL Server 2005 CPU Licensing with Multi-Core Technology](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1164)

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the enterprise edition of sql server. Standard is limited to 4 cores.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143760.aspx